# SQL to BQL assistance

Tags: acumatica

Would anyone know how to write the following from SQL in BQL?

```
   SELECT        *
    FROM            (SELECT        *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY LotSerialNbr
                          ORDER BY LastModifiedDateTime DESC) AS rankid
                          FROM            dbo.INTranSplit
                          WHERE        DocType = 'R') A
    WHERE        rankid = 1
```

I am attempting to get only the most recent inventory receipt from INTranSplit when there are multiple receipts for the same serial number.
Thanks

Comment: This is not easily achievable as is with a single BQL query because BQL doesn't support sub queries without additional development. It could be easier to have an aggregate (group by) query to detect 'when there are multiple' and then another query (not aggregate) to select the individual records. This 2 step querying can be done in a DataView delegate.

Answer (score 1):

The following BQL should get you the same results as your SQL query:

```
PXSelect<INTranSplit, 
    Where<INTranSplit.docType, Equal<INDocType.receipt>, 
        And<NotExists<
                      Select<INTranSplit2,
                          Where<INTranSplit2.lotSerialNbr, Equal<INTranSplit.lotSerialNbr>, 
                              And<INTranSplit2.docType, Equal<INDocType.receipt>, 
                                  And<INTranSplit2.lastModifiedDateTime, Greater<INTranSplit.lastModifiedDateTime>>>>>>>>>.Select(this)
```

You will also have to create a class that derives from INTranSplit:

```
[Serializable]
public class INTranSplit2 : INTranSplit
{
    // Re-declare key fields and fields you are using in your BQL
    public new abstract class lineNbr : IBqlField
    {
    }

    public new abstract class refNbr : IBqlField
    {
    }

    public new abstract class docType : IBqlField
    {
    }

    public new abstract class splitLineNbr : IBqlField
    {
    }

    public new abstract class lotSerialNbr : IBqlField
    {
    }

    public new abstract class lastModifiedDateTime : IBqlField
    {
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that if two INTranSplits have equal LastModifiedDateTime values then these queries will return both INTranSplits. If that is not desirable based on your use case then you can change the query accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

BQL does not have the necessary commands for ranking and partitioning query. One approach you can take is to create a regular SQL view that will return the data you need, and map this SQL view to a standard Acumatica DAC that you can use in generic inquiries and BQL queries. You can read more about this technique here: https://www.acumatica.com/blog/technical-tuesday-report-from-sql-view/